# Bootstrap - datepicker - how to pick US Locale settings

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using date picker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/FAQ/#how-do-i-change-the-languagelocale) and I am struggling to use locale calendar for US. I could get GB working.

Apart from jQuery I attach the following

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/en-gb.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Below are the calendar object

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
     <div class='col-sm-6'>
         <div class="form-group">
             <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                 <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                 <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                 </span>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
         });
     </script>
 </div>
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'en-gb'
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I wonder how can i get US calendar working (without using moment-with-locales.min.js which is a huge file!)

Comment: So what locale does your first code give you? (datetimepicker1)

Comment: datetimepicker1 is picking british calendar by default

Comment: moment-with-locales.min.js is 45k, since when is that huge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include `js/en-gb.js` and don't specify a locale, just like you have for datepicker1.  Specifying the locale as 'en-us' I would think would work as well.

Comment: When I don't include js/en-gb.js, I get only US calendar. My requirement is to bring US calendar(mm/dd/..) when logging from US and British (dd/mm/..) when logging from UK.

Comment: And how do you currently determine whether it's US/UK?   Use the same mechanism to determine whether or not to include `en-gb`

Comment: It looks like the US locale is 'en', but you should be able to specify 'en-us' as well, and it'll fall back to 'en' automatically.

Comment: Thanks Robert. It did the trick! en gives me us format and en-gb gives british. More importantly I can use moment.min.js which is 35kb file instead of moment-with-locals.min.js which is around 171kb. each language file is around 2kb. A big win :)

Comment: Not quite the big win, but still one.  moment-with-locals.min.js is only 45k when gzipped which you should be using to serve your css/js.  You don't need the additional language files if you use moment-with-locals (it contains ALL the language files).  If you are only using en-us + en-gb, you save about 29k.  (moment.min.js is 31k smaller than moment-with-locals.js, but you also need to then include en-gb.js which is ~2k).  Unless you are doing your own js concatenation, you've traded 29k of transfer for an additional server request -- a fairly marginal benefit.